# Yii2 UrlManager и модуль RedactorModule

Tags: yii2, url-manager

**Кратко:** 
Проблема с маршрутом *urlManager*. При включении `urlManager` у модуля *redactor* пропадает возможность загружать изображения.

**Подробно:**
Для редактирования текста имеется модуль *yii\redactor\RedactorModule*
У редактора имеется возможность добавлять изображения в текст.

При включении *urlManager* и попытке добавить изображение появляется две ошибки

http://site.lan/**redactor/upload/image-json**?_=1532085618974

http://site.lan/**redactor/upload/image**

Понимаю что проблема в маршруте, но не могу его написать правильно.

**Конфиг файл common**

```
    'modules' => [
    'redactor' => [
        'class' => 'yii\redactor\RedactorModule',
        'uploadDir' => \Yii::getAlias('@frontend') . '/web/uploads/text_image/',
        'uploadUrl' => '@web/uploads/text_image',
        'imageAllowExtensions'=>['jpg','png','gif']
    ],
],
```

**Сам модуль в backend\view**

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'text')->widget(Redactor::className(),
    [
        'clientOptions' => [
            'lang' => 'ru',
            'buttonSource' => true,
            'plugins' => ['clips', 'fontcolor','imagemanager'],
            'minHeight' => '300px'
        ]
    ]
) ?>
```

**Правила urlManager**

```
       'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '/' => 'site/index',
            'about' => 'site/about',
            'contact' => 'site/contact',
            'login' => 'site/login',

            '<controller:\w+>/' => '<controller>/index',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:(\w|-)+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:(\w|-)+>/<slug:([A-Za-z0-9-])+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:(\w|-)+>' => '<controller>/<action>',


        ],
    ],
```

**Маршрут который пытался добавить, но безрезультатно**

```
'<controller:\w+>/redactor' => '/redactor/upload/image',
```

**Ошибка которую показывает встроенный дебагер**

```
exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request: redactor/upload/' in E:\OSPanel\domains\site.lan\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php:128
Stack trace:
#0 E:\OSPanel\domains\site.lan\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#1 E:\OSPanel\domains\site.lan\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('redactor/upload', Array)
#2 E:\OSPanel\domains\site.lan\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#3 E:\OSPanel\domains\site.lan\backend\web\index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#4 {main}

Next exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Страница не найдена.' in E:\OSPanel\domains\site.lan\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php:115
Stack trace:
#0 E:\OSPanel\domains\site.lan\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#1 E:\OSPanel\domains\site.lan\backend\web\index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы было прям под носом.
У меня был конфликт маршрутов.

Вот следующий маршрут, который будет работать.

```
        '<controller:\w+>/redactor' => '/redactor/upload/image',
        '<controller:\w+>/' => '<controller>/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:(\w|-)+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:(\w|-)+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

Все что я сделал, это удалил лишние маршруты, и добавил следующий маршрут

```
'<controller:\w+>/redactor' => '/redactor/upload/image',
```